# Updating var value in a class from a method within it

Tags: swift

I feel like this is not as difficult as I am making it out to be so any advice would be much appreciated.

I am just messing around in a playground trying to understand classes better.  In a gaming scenario, I made a 'Player' class that has a health value and also an attack value.  The attack value comes from a different class named 'Weapon', each with their own Double value.  I am trying to create a function from within the 'Player' class that when called acts as if a new weapon is being picked up creating a new attack value for the player.

My function called 'weaponPickUp' always says it cannot assign value of Weapon.Type to type Double.  I need any advice to make this function work as intended please!

```
class Player {
    var health = 100.00
    var armor = 0
    var attack: Double

    init() {
        attack = Weapon.init().fist
    }

    func weaponPickUp(weaponPickedUp: Weapon.Type){
        attack = weaponPickedUp
    }

    func attackEnemy(enemy: Enemy) {
        let weaponStrike = enemy.health - attack
        let currentEnemyHealth = weaponStrike

        if currentEnemyHealth > 0 {
            print("Enemy Hit, life remaining \(currentEnemyHealth)")
            enemy.health = currentEnemyHealth
        } else {
            print("Enemy Destroyed")
        }
    }
}


class Weapon {
    var fist = 25.0
    var machette = 35.0
    var special = Enemy.init().health / 2.0
}


class Enemy {
    var health = 100.0
    var armor = 100.0
    var attack1 = 10.0
    var specialAttack = 50.0
}
```

Comment: I won't recommend that you refactor since it's pretty obvious where you are on the learning curve. Instead you should find a tutorial — or, alternatively, *another* tutorial — that introduce these concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this were the whole program, I would definitely write this in Sweeper's style, but it relies on understanding closures, which may be a bit higher learning curve than you want to handle right away. It's also not as flexible if may want it to be if Weapons can have other attributes besides damage.

Another way to approach this problem would be with a simple `Weapon` protocol:

```
protocol Weapon {
    func damage(whenAttacking enemy: Enemy) -> Double
}
```

Now you can have specific weapons. If this were really all a weapon is (a set of stats), then they should probably be structs. But if you track weapons as unique items in the game, you might choose to make them classes. For now, we'll let them be structs (this means that any two Machettes, for example, are the indistinguishable).

```
struct Fist: Weapon {
    func damage(whenAttacking enemy: Enemy) -> Double {
        return 25
    }
}

struct Machette: Weapon {
    func damage(whenAttacking enemy: Enemy) -> Double {
        return 35
    }
}

struct SpecialWeapon: Weapon {
    func damage(whenAttacking enemy: Enemy) -> Double {
        return enemy.health / 2.0
    }
}
```

Now some changes to `Player`. I made some style changes (there's no need for `init` just to set an initial value), and some substantive changes (how damage is calculated).

```
class Player {
    var health = 100.00
    var armor = 0
    var weapon: Weapon = Fist()

    // You'd almost certainly not bother with this method, and just let people call
    //     player.weapon = Machette()
    func pickUp(weapon: Weapon){
        self.weapon = weapon
    }

    func attack(enemy: Enemy) {
        let weaponStrike = enemy.health - weapon.damage(whenAttacking: enemy)
        let currentEnemyHealth = weaponStrike

        if currentEnemyHealth > 0 {
            print("Enemy Hit, life remaining \(currentEnemyHealth)")
            enemy.health = currentEnemyHealth
        } else {
            print("Enemy Destroyed")
        }
    }
}
```

This would be a reasonable approach, but there are of course many, many other ways to do this. In fact, I'd personally move most of the `attack` code into `Enemy` this way:

```
class Enemy {
    private(set) var health = 100.0
    private var armor = 100.0
    private var attack1 = 10.0
    private var specialAttack = 50.0

    var isAlive: Bool {
        return health > 0
    }

    func receiveAttack(from weapon: Weapon) {
        health -= weapon.damage(whenAttacking: self)
        // Personally I'd let health be negative, but feel free to force it to be 0 here   
    }
}
```

And now, `Player.attack` looks like this:

```
func attack(enemy: Enemy) {
    enemy.receiveAttack(from: weapon)

    if enemy.isAlive {
        print("Enemy Hit, life remaining \(enemy.health)")
    } else {
        print("Enemy Destroyed")
    }
}
```

This puts the logic for modifying the enemy's health inside of enemy. If a new enemy had special powers that protected it against Machettes, then that could be put inside of `receiveAttack` without having to modify Player (or any other object).

Comment: This is very helpful! I appreciate the in depth explanation for each change you suggested and looking at this now I completely agree that it makes more sense placing the `attack` code inside of the `Enemy` class.  One question I have though is what is the reasoning of setting the `Enemy` variables to `private`?

Comment: In the current code, I didn't see any reason outsider callers would need access to them, so I made them private. In many cases the best question is "why was this public?" And if you don't have a good answer, make it private. But in the above case I don't know the type well enough to be certain which is best.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Weapon` class is not designed very well. In your `Weapon` class, you seem to have listed types of weapons and their attack damage. But you should not declare them as instance properties. Also, `special` is always going to have a damage of `50` instead of halving the enemy's health (which I guess is what you intended to do).

I redesigned your weapon class into a struct:

```
struct Weapon {
    var damage: (Enemy) -> Double
    static let fist = Weapon { _ in return 25.0 }
    static let machette = Weapon { _ in return 35.0 }
    static let special = Weapon { enemy in return enemy.health / 2.0 }
}
```

`damage` stores a closure that returns the damage of the weapon. I also made `fist`, `machette` and `special` static constants so you can access them without creating a new instance of a weapon.

Here is the changed the player class:

```
class Player {
    var health = 100.00
    var armor = 0
    var weapon: Weapon

    init() {
        weapon = Weapon.fist
    }

    func weaponPickUp(weaponPickedUp: Weapon){
        weapon = weaponPickedUp
    }

    func attackEnemy(enemy: Enemy) {
        let weaponStrike = enemy.health - weapon.damage(enemy)
        let currentEnemyHealth = weaponStrike

        if currentEnemyHealth > 0 {
            print("Enemy Hit, life remaining \(currentEnemyHealth)")
            enemy.health = currentEnemyHealth
        } else {
            print("Enemy Destroyed")
        }
    }
}
```

Since `special` halves the enemy's health, you can't have a constant `attack` value in `Player` independent of how much health the enemy has. So I changed it to a `Weapon` instance. In `attackEnemy`, I wrote `weapon.damage(enemy)` because we need to pass the enemy that we're attacking in order to figure out how much damage the weapon can deal.

Comment: Thanks for this! I am still parsing over all your recommendations to understand it better. I am still trying to wrap my head around when to use structs vs. classes and also the use of closures.  I figured that the way I had the weapons class was more of the problem than anything.